# Changing the PivotItem header template?

Tags: windows-phone-7

By default, the PivotItem's header uses a large font.

I was hoping I could change the HeaderTemplate but no such property is available.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly edit the PivotItems' header. The answer lies in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/75404183-dc8d-41bb-bd9d-cb384c68d72d).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I take it that there is no way to change the header template. This will do though